# how is this circuit working as an amplifier

Tags: transistors, amplifier

The green points are from the video controller output, and yellow point is to the CRT base driver. 
ideally small signals are fed to the base of the transistor but here it goes to the collector via diodes. wondering how  these transistors will do the job of amplification of the signals.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, the transistors are not there to amplify the video signal. Instead, they seem to be functioning as a clamp that keeps the video signals grounded (through two diodes) whenever the red line at the top has less than about 7.7 V on it.

When the voltage is high enough to turn Q202 on, Q203 is turned off and the diode cathodes are pulled up, effectively switching them off and allowing the video signals to operate over their full range.